# How do ESD monitors work?

Tags: esd

How do ESD monitors work? Especially those dealing with one wired ESD wrist band. All I've been able to grasp is that the human body acts as a capacitor between the wrist band and the ground. But I don't understand how you can detect if an operator is wearing the wrist band or not. Should you run a current through him?
If anyone knows the answer a detailed explanation would be very appreciated.

[image]

Comment: What ESD monitors?  Can you link to an example?

Comment: @JRE There are plenty of them, a google search for "ESD monitors" will give a variety of them. https://www.correctproducts.com/ESD-Cleanroom-Products/ESD-Constant-Monitors/3M-724-Workstation-Monitor.html.

Answer (score 1):

An ESD monitor or ESD tester like this:

[image]

is like a crude **resistance meter**.

ESD (Electro Static **Discharge**) events are caused by charge that is **trapped**. This charge will try to find its way to **ground** as soon as it can. This might be through a sensitive device which can be damaged.

To prevent that damage we have to make sure that **no charge buildup** can take place. That is done by connecting everything to ground **including humans**. The connection doesn't need to be very low ohmic (have a low resistance), even if there's a 1 M ohm resistor in series between the human and ground, that will still work.

Actually having some resistance in place between the human and ground is preferred as that prevents a **large current** from flowing when the human accidentally touches a mains live connection. Would you like to touch 240 V AC while your other hand is directly grounded? Neither would I but if the ground connection has 1 Mohm in series it becomes a lot safer.

That's that the ESD test station tests. It measures the resistance between your body (you need to touch a metal pad with your finger) and ground. If you're properly grounded with a safe 1 Mohm ESD wristband the test station will indicate everything is OK. If no connection at all is measured then you will fail the test.

So: an ESD monitor/tester measures the resistance between your body and ground.

Comment: I think the question aims at the monitoring systems to check whether a person is wearing the wrist band or forgot to use it. As far as I know they work by detecting the body capacity of that person.

Comment: Thank you Bimpelrekkie for your reply and for the explanation but as jusaca said what i seek to know is how do the monitors work not the testers, those that give signals when an operator forgot to wear the wrist band. I know they do it by detecting the body capacity of the worker but how they do that when there is only one wire feedback?

Answer (score 0):

The [monitor shown in the image](https://transforming-technologies.com/product/cm1602-ranger-two-dual-wire-constant-monitor/) has "Dual Wire" in its name, and the image actually shows that there are two wires.

One wire has the usual 1 MΩ resistor to connect the body to ground; the other wire connects directly to the body so that the resistance of the other wire can be measured.

When the wristband is worn, the body connects the two wires.

Comment: Do they shove a charge into the finger or the clip ? because the monitors have the  wristband to work with, not the human hand.  This is a link to one of the monitors  in case you are mistaking it for the tester: https://www.correctproducts.com/ESD-Cleanroom-Products/ESD-Constant-Monitors/3M-724-Workstation-Monitor.html

Comment: That monitor works differently; updated.